# in Makefile, 'missing separator error' in $subst function but placing a tab before 'subst' removes the error.. why?

Tags: makefile

#### * I modified this question to show only the key point after I figured out what's wrong from the comments I received

This is a part of Makefile during my test.  The ASM_OPTS_AARCH64 value was exported from a top level Makefile and contains a valid string. And this gives me `missing separator error` in line 44 and 46. But if I place a tab before subst, the error goes out. Why is this happening?

```
all: $(target)

$(info ASM_OPTS_AARCH64 = $(ASM_OPTS_AARCH64))
$(subst common, ../../common, $(ASM_OPTS_AARCH64))   <== line 44
$(info LINK_OPTS_CSRC_AARCH64 sub = $(LINK_OPTS_CSRC_AARCH64))
$(subst link, ../../link, $(LINK_OPTS_CSRC_AARCH64))    <== line 46
```

Comment: What are those lines supposed to do?

Comment: it is for fixing the file/directory location included in the compile or link options. The option are used at the top Makefile and also in the sub directories. The locations should be changed seen from subdirectories so I placed ../.. before the file/directory locations for use in the sub Makfiles. First time doing this trick..

Comment: Then you need to prepend `ASM_OPTS_AARCH64 :=` to it.

Comment: What @HolyBlackCat was probably asking is: as you don't assign the result of these substitutions to variables, what effect do you think they will have? They will probably output some strings that will not be any valid make construct. You should probably spend some time reading the documentation (at least of the functions you try to use).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Oh, I realized what you mean. Thanks! (you can write a short answer so I can select it.. ) I thought about deleting this question, but I think it is worth being keept.